# Can someone help me to evaluate this integral?

Tags: integration, geometry, circles

Can someone help me to evaluate this integral? 
$$\int \limits _0 ^\beta \frac{\sin\theta}r\,d\theta$$

I need it in a physics exercise.
[image: See the image here]
Given a circle (as shown in diagram), a point $P$ and angle $\theta$ made with the axis.

Comment: you have to write r as a function of $\theta$

Comment: it's also unclear what the integral is trying to evaluate

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the circle to be of radius $R$ and its center to be $(0,0)$ and $P=(-a,0)$, we have the point where the ray intersects the circle at $(R\cos\eta,R\sin\eta)$ and so
\begin{align}
\sin\theta & = \frac{R\sin\eta}{\sqrt{(a+R\cos\eta)^2 + R\sin^2\eta}} = \frac{R\sin\eta}{\sqrt{R^2+a^2 + 2aR\cos\eta}}, \\[10pt]
r & = \sqrt{(a+R\cos\eta)^2 + R\sin^2\eta} = \sqrt{R^2+a^2 + 2aR\cos\eta}, \\[15pt]
\text{so } \frac{\sin\theta} r & = \frac{R\sin\eta}{R^2+a^2 + 2aR\cos\eta}, \\[10pt]
\text{and } d\theta & = \frac{R^2+aR\cos\eta}{R^2+a^2 + 2aR\cos\eta} \, d\eta.
\end{align}
It's a rational function of sine and cosine, so if all else fails, the standard tangent half-angle substitution will handle it.

**PS:** Maybe I should be explicit about the derivation of $d\theta$.  We have
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}} = \frac{R\cos\eta}{a+R\sin\eta}
$$
so
$$
\theta = \arctan \frac{R\cos\eta}{a+R\sin\eta}
$$
and then differentiate.